# (key-binding (this-command-keys)) not translating keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, company-mode, keymap, functions

I have put the following code (partially adapted from [a `company-mode` issue](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/530#issuecomment-226566961) and [a Stack Exchange question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13286/12534)) in [my `init.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/radian/blob/7ae63a1295a68cc9796e558dfbabe42357c0bcc8/init.el#L487) in order to adjust the keybindings active in the `company-mode` completions menu:

```
(defun company-complete-if-explicit ()
  "Complete the current selection, but only if the user has interacted
explicitly with Company."
  (interactive)
  (if (company-explicit-action-p)
      (company-complete)
    (call-interactively
     (key-binding (this-command-keys)))))

(define-key company-active-map (kbd "<return>") #'company-complete-if-explicit)
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "RET") #'company-complete-if-explicit)
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "TAB") #'company-complete-selection)
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "SPC") nil)

(setq company-auto-complete-chars nil)
```

In terminal Emacs, pressing `RET` will dismiss the completions menu and insert a newline. However, if I have explicitly interacted with the menu (for instance, using `up` and `down`), then `RET` will instead insert the selected completion.

The problem is that this doesn't work in windowed Emacs: if I press `<return>` while the completions menu is showing (but I *haven't* explicitly interacted with it), then instead of Emacs inserting a newline, I receive the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument commandp nil)
  call-interactively(nil)
  (if (company-explicit-action-p) (company-complete) (call-interactively (key-binding (this-command-keys))))
  company-complete-if-explicit()
  call-interactively(company-complete-if-explicit nil nil)
  command-execute(company-complete-if-explicit)
```

I debugged this, and here is what I think is happening:

- In windowed Emacs, the Return key sends `<return>` instead of `RET`.
- Only `RET` has a binding (to `newline`), but normally `<return>` is translated automatically to `RET`, so the Return key still inserts a newline in windowed Emacs.
- When I call `this-command-keys` in `company-complete-if-explicit`, the returned value is `<return>`.
- The `key-binding` function does not appear to do the key translation that usually occurs, so that `(key-binding (kbd "RET"))` is `newline` but `(key-binding (kbd "<return>"))` is `nil`.
- The error is thrown because `nil` is then passed to `call-interactively`.

My question is therefore: what is the best way to fix this problem (either by making `key-binding` perform automatic translations, or otherwise)?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer at the moment, but if I read your intent correctly, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090517/elisp-conditionally-change-keybinding/22863701#22863701) seems to be quite relevant.

Comment: @PythonNut It's beautiful and perfect! The patch is at: https://github.com/raxod502/radian/commit/af57ab37d7532f1441fa39e72733d473502800ff I will add an answer summarizing it, unless you would like to add your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to replace

```
(defun company-complete-if-explicit ()
  "Complete the current selection, but only if the user has interacted
explicitly with Company."
  (interactive)
  (if (company-explicit-action-p)
      (company-complete)
    (call-interactively
     (key-binding (this-command-keys)))))

;; <return> is for windowed Emacs; RET is for terminal Emacs
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "<return>") #'company-complete-if-explicit)
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "RET") #'company-complete-if-explicit)
```

with

```
;; <return> is for windowed Emacs; RET is for terminal Emacs
(dolist (key '("<return>" "RET"))
  ;; Here we are using an advanced feature of define-key that lets
  ;; us pass an "extended menu item" instead of an interactive
  ;; function. Doing this allows RET to regain its usual
  ;; functionality when the user has not explicitly interacted with
  ;; Company.
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd key)
    `(menu-item nil company-complete
                :filter ,(lambda (cmd)
                           (when (company-explicit-action-p)
                             cmd)))))
```

Now `RET` will act like normal when I don't interact with Company, but it will insert the selected completion when I have interacted with Company—in both terminal and windowed Emacs.

[Here](https://github.com/raxod502/radian/commit/af57ab37d7532f1441fa39e72733d473502800ff) is the complete patch.